# Is it possible to insert record into view without using "instead of " trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, sql-insert

I have this view which joins multiple tables and I could not implement a normal insert as it was in conflict with constraints and I implemented it using instead of trigger.But, they say using trigger is not a good idea. Is there any other way to implement insert on a view?

Comment: Tu be clear, you're trying to insert into the trigger? If so, I think the trigger approach is the only eat to do it.

Comment: I am doing trigger and that works fine but I want to explore other possible ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the insert into the table(s) the view selects from.

Comment: Thanks ! that works but still if I want to work on view what is possible way apart from using trigger when multiple tables are involved?

Answer (score 0):

When you query the view, you will effectively run the query that defines the view, meaning your view will automatically sync with the underlying source data